# How to analyze the effect of treatment on a multi-variable dataset?

Tags: r, manova

I would like to analyze effect of a treatment on my patient samples. I have measurement of 3 different protein level for treated and untreated patients. Now I would like to analyze effect of my treatment on the whole different protein measurements and not each individually (sort of summing them up together).
Someone suggest me I can use MANOVA but I am not really sure if I should use MANOVA or not.

An example line of my dataset:

```
        CD13    CD68     AT1     treatment
sample1 0.065   0.82     0.488   +
sample2 0       1.58     0.47    -
```

I have around 30 replicates for each treated and untreated patient group.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like MANOVA is what you want.  MANOVA linearly combines the DV measures into a "new" compounded DV. However, be aware that there are several assumptions underlying MANOVA.  Stats packages like SPSS provide tests of the important assumptions. Do you have access to a reference source that describes the assumptions behind MANOVA and how to test them? (Fortunately, MANOVA is pretty robust in the face of violation of most of these assumptions.)

Comment: Thanks Meg. Actually, I don't know and I don't have any reference. it would be great if you give me any. Unfortunately, I am not using SPSS. I am used to R, is it possible to test all these in R also?

Comment: Yes, R does do MANOVA but I'm not personally R proficient so I couldn't tell you how to do it.  Just about any good intro text on multivariate analysis (that's the key phrase) will take you through the assumptions.  People seem to like Tabachnick and Fidell's "Using Multivariate Statistics".  Stevens' Applied Multivariate Statistics for the Social Sciences has a whole chapter on assumptions of MANOVA and how to test whether they are met.